# OnClick event and tooltip on a disabled CheckBox button in MFC

Tags: c++, checkbox, onclick, mfc, disabled-control

Is it possible to capture OnClick event when the CheckBox is disabled and then, to display a tooltip that shows why it is so (based on some business requirements)?

I looked up many sources over the internet, but I was able to find the answer to the second part of the question, not tested though. It seems to be a well-known problem, but I cannot find any answer or a hint.

I have to say that I am not a master of MFC, so a small code snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: IMO this is a very poor user interface. Usually you don't want to click on a disabled item in first place. I'd do either this: don't disable the control and display the tooltip when the user clicks on the control, or this: display a tool tip as soon as the user hovers over the disabled control.

Comment: A [disabled window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#disabled-windows) does not receive keyboard or mouse input. This is not a *"well-known problem"*. It is a design decision of the system you are targeting. The problem you are trying to solve is one you created yourself by forcing the system to behave in a certain way it was not designed to behave.

Comment: @Jabberwocky
The use case is the following: 
1. Dialog is shown to the user. 
2. User sees the disabled control. 
3. User wants to know the exact reason why the control is disabled. 
4. User clicks on the disabled control. 
5. User is notified why he or she cannot access given functionality.
So, we want the user to know up front that he or she cannot access some functionality, but also we want to inform the user why it is so. Having enabled control is not too elegant in such situation.

Comment: @Izi then I think my second solution is the best one, you display the control as disabled and when you hover on that control, you show a tooltip, no need to click on the disabled control.

Comment: @IInspectable This is a design decision which is NOT made by me. That is why I am trying to find some workarounds, if any comes into your mind.

Comment: @Izi maybe you should discuss the design decision with the person who made it. If you present reasonable arguments, he might change his mind. Needing to _click_ on a disabled control to get the informatino why it's disabled is just ... strange. I think my second solution is the best compromise.

Comment: Obviously, the design of the Windows GUI wasn't done by you. That doesn't mean, that it wasn't meant *for* you. I'm positive, that you even rely on that design (you surely do display modal dialogs every now and again). If you want to present information to the user, do what your users expect: Add a static control with a question mark icon that your users can hover over to see a tooltip, or open the appropriate section of your documentation on click. Users have been educated, that you cannot click disabled controls. Don't make them learn a new set of rules that apply only to your application.